# How do I vertically center these buttons in the middle of the container in bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

This is going to be a stupid question, but for some reason, I'm having trouble center aligning these buttons in the middle of the page.

I want to them to stack on top of each other in the middle of the overlay, but right not they are stuck at the top of the overlay. Can you guys help me out?

[image]

Here is my sample HTML:

```
<h1 class="text-center">Portfolio</h1>
    <div class="row p-5">
      <div class=" col-sm-6 col-xl-4 mb-3">
        <div class="card">
          <img src="img/image-1.jpg" class="card-img-top" alt="image-1">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title text-center">Project 1</h5>
          </div>
          <div id="overlay">
            <div class="d-flex flex-column align-content-center">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Demo</button>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">Github Repo</button>
            </div>
          </div> 
        </div>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `display: flex`to `#overlay`, and both `flex: 1` and `justify-content: center` to the children (which you can taret with `#overlay > div`):

```
#overlay {
  display: flex;
}

#overlay > div {
  flex: 1;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

This can be seen **[here](https://jsfiddle.net/juL1kdgf/)**.

```js
typewriterContainer = document.querySelector('#typewriter');

const typewriter = new Typewriter(typewriterContainer, {
  loop: false,
  delay: 75
});

typewriter
  .typeString("<h1 class='display-4'>Hi, I'm Aman!</h1>")
  .typeString("<p class='lead'>I am learning how to program. I love tech. I am an aspiring entrepreneur. I want to change the world. </p>")
  .start();

/* particlesJS.load(@dom-id, @path-json, @callback (optional)); */
particlesJS.load('particles-js', 'particles.json', function() {
  console.log('particles.json loaded');
});
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

img[alt="Profile Picture"] {
  width: 40%;
}


/* why do this work idk */

img {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}

.about {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
}

#particles-js {
  background: rgb(72, 243, 29);
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
}

.svg-div {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}

svg {
  width: 100%;
}

span {
  font-size: 12px;
}

.nav {
  min-height: 40px;
}

.card {
  box-shadow: 8px 8px 10px #080808;
  transition: transform ease 0.1s;
  position: relative;
}

#overlay {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  transition: 0.02s ease-in;
  display: flex;
}

#overlay>div {
  flex: 1;
  justify-content: center;
}

.card:hover {
  transform: scale(1.1);
}

.hire {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 47%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <title>Capstone Project</title>
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
</head>

<body>

  <!-- navigation bar -->
  <ul class="nav sticky-top justify-content-around">
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link active" href="#">About Me</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Portfolio</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Skills</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact Me</a>
    </li>
  </ul>

  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary hire" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModalCenter">
    Hire Me
  </button>

  <div class="about">
    <img src="img/profile-picture.jpg" class="img-fluid rounded mx-auto d-block shadow p-3 mb-5" alt="Profile Picture">
    <div id="typewriter" class="container text-center">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="particles-js">
  </div>


  <!-- portfolio -->

  <h1 class="text-center">Portfolio</h1>
  <div class="row p-5">
    <div class=" col-sm-6 col-xl-4 mb-3">
      <div class="card">
        <img src="img/image-1.jpg" class="card-img-top" alt="image-1">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title text-center">Project 1</h5>
        </div>
        <div id="overlay">
          <div class="d-flex flex-column align-content-center">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Demo</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">Github Repo</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>


    <div class="col-sm-6 col-xl-4 mb-3">
      <div class="card">
        <img src="img/image-2.jpg" class="card-img-top" alt="image-2">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title text-center">Project 2</h5>
        </div>
        <div class="overlay">

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-6 col-xl-4 mb-3">
      <div class="card">
        <img src="img/image-3.jpg" class="card-img-top" alt="image-3">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title text-center">Project 3</h5>
        </div>
        <div class="overlay">

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class=" col-sm-6 col-xl-4 mb-3">
      <div class="card">
        <img src="img/image-4.JPG" class="card-img-top" alt="image-4">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title text-center">Project 4</h5>
        </div>
        <div class="overlay">

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-6 col-xl-4 mb-3">
      <div class="card">
        <img src="img/image-5.jpg" class="card-img-top" alt="image-5">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title text-center">Project 5</h5>
        </div>
        <div class="overlay">

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class=" col-sm-6 col-xl-4 mb-3">
      <div class="card">
        <img src="img/image-6.jpg" class="card-img-top" alt="image-6">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title text-center">Project 6</h5>
        </div>
        <div class="overlay">

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- contact-section -->



  <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModalCenter" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalCenterTitle" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLongTitle">Contact Information</h5>
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
          </button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <form>
            <div class="form-group row">
              <label for="inputName3" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Name:</label>
              <div class="col-sm-10">
                <input type="name" class="form-control" id="inputName3" placeholder="Name">
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group row">
              <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Email:</label>
              <div class="col-sm-10">
                <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail3" placeholder="Email">
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group row">
              <label for="inputNumber3" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Phone Number:</label>
              <div class="col-sm-10">
                <input type="number" class="form-control" id="inputNumber3" placeholder="Number">
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group row">
              <label for="exampleFormControlTextarea1" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Message:</label>
              <div class="col-sm-10">
                <textarea class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlTextarea1" rows="5"></textarea>
              </div>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">

    <div class="svg-div ml-3 mr-3">
      <svg version="1.1" id="Capa_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 90 90" style="enable-background:new 0 0 90 90;" xml:space="preserve">
        <path id="Facebook__x28_alt_x29_" d="M90,15.001C90,7.119,82.884,0,75,0H15C7.116,0,0,7.119,0,15.001v59.998
          C0,82.881,7.116,90,15.001,90H45V56H34V41h11v-5.844C45,25.077,52.568,16,61.875,16H74v15H61.875C60.548,31,59,32.611,59,35.024V41
          h15v15H59v34h16c7.884,0,15-7.119,15-15.001V15.001z" />
      </svg>
    </div>

    <div class="svg-div ml-3 mr-3">
      <svg class="svg-twitter" version="1.1" id="Capa_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 430.117 430.117" style="enable-background:new 0 0 430.117 430.117;" xml:space="preserve">
        <path id="Twitter__x28_alt_x29_" d="M381.384,198.639c24.157-1.993,40.543-12.975,46.849-27.876
          c-8.714,5.353-35.764,11.189-50.703,5.631c-0.732-3.51-1.55-6.844-2.353-9.854c-11.383-41.798-50.357-75.472-91.194-71.404
          c3.304-1.334,6.655-2.576,9.996-3.691c4.495-1.61,30.868-5.901,26.715-15.21c-3.5-8.188-35.722,6.188-41.789,8.067
          c8.009-3.012,21.254-8.193,22.673-17.396c-12.27,1.683-24.315,7.484-33.622,15.919c3.36-3.617,5.909-8.025,6.45-12.769
          C241.68,90.963,222.563,133.113,207.092,174c-12.148-11.773-22.915-21.044-32.574-26.192
          c-27.097-14.531-59.496-29.692-110.355-48.572c-1.561,16.827,8.322,39.201,36.8,54.08c-6.17-0.826-17.453,1.017-26.477,3.178
          c3.675,19.277,15.677,35.159,48.169,42.839c-14.849,0.98-22.523,4.359-29.478,11.642c6.763,13.407,23.266,29.186,52.953,25.947
          c-33.006,14.226-13.458,40.571,13.399,36.642C113.713,320.887,41.479,317.409,0,277.828
          c108.299,147.572,343.716,87.274,378.799-54.866c26.285,0.224,41.737-9.105,51.318-19.39
          C414.973,206.142,393.023,203.486,381.384,198.639z" />
      </svg>
    </div>

    <div class="svg-div ml-3 mr-3">
      <svg version="1.1" id="Capa_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 430.117 430.118" style="enable-background:new 0 0 430.117 430.118;" xml:space="preserve">
        <path id="LinkedIn__x28_alt_x29_" d="M398.355,0H31.782C14.229,0,0.002,13.793,0.002,30.817v368.471
          c0,17.025,14.232,30.83,31.78,30.83h366.573c17.549,0,31.76-13.814,31.76-30.83V30.817C430.115,13.798,415.904,0,398.355,0z
          M130.4,360.038H65.413V165.845H130.4V360.038z M97.913,139.315h-0.437c-21.793,0-35.92-14.904-35.92-33.563
          c0-19.035,14.542-33.535,36.767-33.535c22.227,0,35.899,14.496,36.331,33.535C134.654,124.415,120.555,139.315,97.913,139.315z
          M364.659,360.038h-64.966V256.138c0-26.107-9.413-43.921-32.907-43.921c-17.973,0-28.642,12.018-33.327,23.621
          c-1.736,4.144-2.166,9.94-2.166,15.728v108.468h-64.954c0,0,0.85-175.979,0-194.192h64.964v27.531
          c8.624-13.229,24.035-32.1,58.534-32.1c42.76,0,74.822,27.739,74.822,87.414V360.038z M230.883,193.99
          c0.111-0.182,0.266-0.401,0.42-0.614v0.614H230.883z" />
      </svg>
    </div>

  </div>
  <!-- footer -->
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="d-flex justify-content-between">
      <p>Copyright 2019<span>&#169;</span></p>
      <p>Back to Top</p>
    </div>
  </div>



  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/typewriter-effect@latest/dist/core.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/particles.js@2.0.0/particles.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/app.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Note that if you also want them to display as 'buttons' (as opposed to taking up the full `width` of the overlay, you can apply `align-items: center`.

Comment: @AmandeepPasricha you don't want your site to look like a regular bootstrap website, when you need to customize, you really do add additional CSS classes. Most of the websites and plugins out there have classes that don't belong to bootstrap library.

Comment: It really comes down to personal preference. All Bootstrap is doing is creating classes for you to make your life easier. If you want a 'vanilla' layout, you could argue that pure Bootstrap classes are better. If you want some modification, obviously you'll need your own classes. The equivalent to `display: flex` (and `flex: 1` on the child) is the class `.d-flex`, and the equivalent to `justify-content: center` is `.justify-content-center`. Which you use is up to you :)

Comment: @ObsidianAge <3 your last comment

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the parent div "overlay" to position:relative and the child elements to position:absolute .

Answer (score 0):

Your code already contains `.align-content-center`.Just u can add the below given properties to `.align-content-center` class.

```
.align-content-center {
    position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        width: 100%;
        left: 50%;
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%);    
    }
```

check it out:https://jsfiddle.net/hgf5m9kq/

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way without display flex;

1. add z-index to #overlay,
2. add position absolute to .d-flex,
3. then move .d-flex outside of #overlay.

CSS Update:

```
#overlay {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  transition: 0.02s ease-in;
  z-index: 99999;
}

.d-flex.flex-column.align-content-center{
  position:absolute;
  width:100%;
}
```

Layout update:

```
<div class="card">
   <img src="img/image-1.jpg" class="card-img-top" alt="image-1">
   <div class="card-body">
     <h5 class="card-title text-center">Project 1</h5>
   </div>
   <div id="overlay"></div>
   <div class="d-flex flex-column align-content-center">
     <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Demo</button>
     <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">Github Repo</button>
   </div>
</div>
```

Result:

[image: screenshot]